# Serialize and post but unable unserialize

Tags: php

Serialize and post but unable unserialize

This is my input data after using serialize on an array

```
<input type='hidden' name='play_data' value='a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:7:"play_day";s:1:"6";s:10:"play_number";s:4:"1872";s:7:"play_big";s:1:"1";s:9:"play_small";s:1:"1";s:8:"play_user";s:2:"b1";s:8:"play_page";s:3:"001";s:8:"play_roll";s:1:"Y";}i:1;a:7:{s:7:"play_day";s:1:"6";s:10:"play_number";s:4:"1873";s:7:"play_big";s:1:"2";s:9:"play_small";s:1:"0";s:8:"play_user";s:2:"b1";s:8:"play_page";s:3:"001";s:8:"play_roll";s:1:"Y";}}'>
```

When I post over

```
$play_data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['play_data']);
echo $play_data;
```

it give me an output of

```
a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:7:\\\"play_day\\\";s:1:\\\"6\\\";s:10:\\\"play_number\\\";s:4:\\\"1872\\\";s:7:\\\"play_big\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:9:\\\"play_small\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:8:\\\"play_user\\\";s:2:\\\"b1\\\";s:8:\\\"play_page\\\";s:3:\\\"001\\\";s:8:\\\"play_roll\\\";s:1:\\\"Y\\\";}i:1;a:7:{s:7:\\\"play_day\\\";s:1:\\\"6\\\";s:10:\\\"play_number\\\";s:4:\\\"1873\\\";s:7:\\\"play_big\\\";s:1:\\\"2\\\";s:9:\\\"play_small\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:8:\\\"play_user\\\";s:2:\\\"b1\\\";s:8:\\\"play_page\\\";s:3:\\\"001\\\";s:8:\\\"play_roll\\\";s:1:\\\"Y\\\";}}

$play_data = unserialize($play_data);
echo $play_data;
```

It return nothing for this

How do I retrieve my array before serialize at the post.

Serialize and post but unable unserialize

This is my input data after using serialize on an array

```
<input type='hidden' name='play_data' value='a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:7:"play_day";s:1:"6";s:10:"play_number";s:4:"1872";s:7:"play_big";s:1:"1";s:9:"play_small";s:1:"1";s:8:"play_user";s:2:"b1";s:8:"play_page";s:3:"001";s:8:"play_roll";s:1:"Y";}i:1;a:7:{s:7:"play_day";s:1:"6";s:10:"play_number";s:4:"1873";s:7:"play_big";s:1:"2";s:9:"play_small";s:1:"0";s:8:"play_user";s:2:"b1";s:8:"play_page";s:3:"001";s:8:"play_roll";s:1:"Y";}}'>
```

When I post over

```
$play_data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['play_data']);
echo $play_data;
```

it give me an output of

```
a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:7:\\\"play_day\\\";s:1:\\\"6\\\";s:10:\\\"play_number\\\";s:4:\\\"1872\\\";s:7:\\\"play_big\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:9:\\\"play_small\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:8:\\\"play_user\\\";s:2:\\\"b1\\\";s:8:\\\"play_page\\\";s:3:\\\"001\\\";s:8:\\\"play_roll\\\";s:1:\\\"Y\\\";}i:1;a:7:{s:7:\\\"play_day\\\";s:1:\\\"6\\\";s:10:\\\"play_number\\\";s:4:\\\"1873\\\";s:7:\\\"play_big\\\";s:1:\\\"2\\\";s:9:\\\"play_small\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:8:\\\"play_user\\\";s:2:\\\"b1\\\";s:8:\\\"play_page\\\";s:3:\\\"001\\\";s:8:\\\"play_roll\\\";s:1:\\\"Y\\\";}}

$play_data = unserialize($play_data);
echo $play_data;
```

It return nothing for this

How do I retrieve my array before serialize at the post.

#

**Updates:**

For those who recommend me take away mysql_escape_string.

this is the php code

```
$play_data = $_POST['play_data'];

echo "Play Data without Unserialize<br/>" . $bet_data;


$play_data = unserialize($play_data);

echo "Play Data with Unserialize<br/>" . $bet_data
```

;

this is the output

```
Play Data without Unserialize
a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:7:\"play_day\";s:1:\"6\";s:10:\"play_number\";s:4:\"1872\";s:7:\"play_big\";s:1:\"1\";s:9:\"play_small\";s:1:\"1\";s:8:\"play_user\";s:2:\"b1\";s:8:\"play_page\";s:3:\"001\";s:8:\"play_roll\";s:1:\"Y\";}i:1;a:7:{s:7:\"play_day\";s:1:\"6\";s:10:\"play_number\";s:4:\"1873\";s:7:\"play_big\";s:1:\"2\";s:9:\"play_small\";s:1:\"0\";s:8:\"play_user\";s:2:\"b1\";s:8:\"play_page\";s:3:\"001\";s:8:\"play_roll\";s:1:\"Y\";}}

PLay Data with Unserialize
```

Comment: `unserialize($_POST['play_data']);`

Comment: @Musa Check my new updated output and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't add slashes before you unserialize it.

Next you cant echo an array. You have to use print_r() instead.

So just use:

```
print_r(unserialize($_POST['play_data']));
```

Edit:
Since it is still adding slashes, try this:

```
print_r(unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['play_data'])));
```

Comment: you are still adding slashes somewhere and you are still trying to echo an array

Comment: please check again, I din't add slash, I receive $_POST right away after post.

Comment: Well either way its adding them somewhere. See my edit for a solution.

Comment: btw its probably adding them because magic quotes is turned on in your server configuration

Comment: Brian, would it have issue if magic quote is turn off and I use strip slashes will it still work

Comment: Yes it will still work. It will try to remove slashes but since there wouldnt be any it wouldn't do anything.